# How to replace all consecutive underscore with a single space in scala code?

Tags: javascript, regex, scala

I want to replace all the consecutive underscore with a single space character. I am able to do so with the following *javascript* code. But I am not able to do so with *scala*. Below is given my *javascript* code.

```
var name = "cust_id";
var newName = name.replace(/[\W_]+/g, " ");
console.log(newName);
```

Below is given my scala code

```
val regex: Regex = new Regex("/[\W_]+/g")
val name: String = "cust_id"
val newName: String = regex.replaceAllIn(name, " ")
println(newName)
```

I am given the following error.

> invalid escape character

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala: How to replace all consecutive underscore with a single space?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982078/scala-how-to-replace-all-consecutive-underscore-with-a-single-space)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala, as in Java, a single backslash is an escape character in a (standard) string literal, so you need to double it to put an actual backslash in the string to be used to initialise the Regex:

```
val regex: Regex = new Regex("/[\\W_]+/g")
```

Alternatively, you can 'triple-quote' the string, to prevent the usual escaping behaviour:

```
val regex: Regex = new Regex("""/[\W_]+/g""")
```

Comment: Thank you. I am not getting an error right now. But I am not able to replace the underscore "cust_id" with a space.